# Custom response on bad request using spring RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have the following controller. I am using Spring to create Restful APIs.

```
@RestController
public class UserController extends RestControlValidator {

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json", consumes = "application/json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List newUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserInput input,BindingResult result) 
            {Some code}

}
```

The `UserInput` class looks like this:

```
public class UserInput{

    @NotEmpty
    private String emailId;
    @NotEmpty
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private int sex;

//getters and setters
```

Now when I try and access `/user/` with data `{"sex":"Male"}`, I get the following response:

[image: Bad request response]

I want the response in case of such a request to be:

```
{"errors":{"sex":"The value must be an integer"}}
```

Is there any way of customising `BAD REQUEST` responses in Spring?

Comment: @Mudassar It is intended to be a post request. And I access it via POST. The status code of response is as expected. I just want to alter the response I get for a BAD REQUEST

Comment: Sorry buddy I realised that late hence immediately removed

Comment: The validation that you are looking for, is it only for the sex variable or would it apply to all the variable types.

Comment: @Mudassar Not just one variable. I wish to generalise the response for 400 response code. Depending upon for what field the BAD REQUEST was raised, I wish to modify the response provided by the API. e.g. The response could be `{"errors":{"fName":"This field cannot be empty"}}`

Comment: you may want to check out this solution [http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/09/generating-json-error-object-responses-with-spring-web-mvc](http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/09/generating-json-error-object-responses-with-spring-web-mvc)

Comment: @Amit.rk3 Referring the blog link posted by you:The problem is the flow never gets to `if (bindingResult.hasErrors())`. I tried running it in debug mode but the response is returned before the Controller code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the current scenario the most ideal solution would be to alter the behavior of HandlerMethodArgumentResolve as the json to pojo constructed by @RequestBody fails because we dont get a chance to check the wrong data and this check can very well be done in the custom message converter

A. first we would need to create LanguageMessageConverter as follows

```
public class LanguageMessageConverter extends
        AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Language> {
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
public LanguageMessageConverter() {
    super(new MediaType("application", "json", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
}

@Override
protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Language.class.equals(clazz);
}

Map<String, String> mp = new HashMap<>();

@Override
protected Language readInternal(Class<? extends Language> clazz,
        HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage) throws IOException,
        HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    Map langmp = gson.fromJson(
            convertStreamToString(httpInputMessage.getBody()), Map.class);

        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {

            if (!langmp.get(field.getName()).getClass().getCanonicalName().equals(field.getType().getCanonicalName())) {
                if (field.getType().getCanonicalName().equals("java.lang.Integer")||field.getType().getCanonicalName().toString().equals("int")) {
                    langmp.put(field.getName(), "0");
                } else if (field.getType().equals("java.lang.String")) {
//TODO COde needs to be improved here because this check is not efficient
                    langmp.put(field.getName(), "wrong");
                }
            }
        }       
        Language lang = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(langmp), clazz);
        return lang;
    }
```

1. we need to set the media type new MediaType("application", "json", Charset.forName("UTF-8")) which will make sure this class intervenes the mentioned MIME type
2. Considering we need to manipulate the result I found it best to convert it to map `langmp` (There are better JSON Parsers which can be used)
3. Since we need to to understand the existing type I used reflection api to get the fields via getDeclaredFields()
4. Using the above made the logical check using the datatype to understand if the type is incorrect for eg if the field datatype is int and if it is found as String then corresponding map value will be substituted
5. once that is done the map will hold the updated values where in if the data was wrong a default value would be set eg if the int var is set to 0 since the originating json had a String in it.
6. Once that is done the updated map is converted to the concerned class.

B. Secondly we need to register the custom MessageConverter in the dispatcher xml i.e. `LanguageMessageConverter`

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
   <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">       
       <bean class="com.comp.org.controller.LanguageMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

1. `register-defaults="true"` is very important since we are adding Custom MessageConverter but we also need the other existing converters working along with the one we have added
2. LanguageMessageConverter needs to be registered here.

C. Considering the concerned pojo is populated with the necessary details it would reach our controller post processing in the custom converter now we would add the manual validation eg. if the int variable has 0 the necessary error json should be returned

As per your request even if the json consists of the wrong data the custom message converter should process it and accordingly in the controller we can validate the condition mentioned. 
The code definitely can be improved further. Kindly let me know if this solution fulfilled your requirement or any part of the code requires further elaboration and hopefully addressed your concern.

Comment: How do you get access to the `BindingResult` (which they already have) if Spring responds with a 400?

Comment: I have responded with the part of the solution of how the expected error json can be constructed. Kindly let me know if any part is incorrect or didn't  add value to the solution.

Comment: The OP already has the `BindingResult` in their handler method. We can assume they were planning to use it. If Spring is responding with 400, it never got to call the handler method, so where would OP do what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Mudassar The problem is the flow never gets to `if (result.hasErrors())`. I tried running it in debug mode but the response is returned before the Controller code is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs for clarification of the requirement. Kindly check the updated solution which should sort your problem.

Comment: Kindly let me know if this solution addressed your problem or if there are still issues regarding the same.

Comment: Kindly close the question by accepting the proposed solution else kindly share the problem being faced with the steps mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. I found an alternate solution.

Comment: No worries buddy but can you please post that alternate solution here and close the question but accepting that as the answer so that it would help people in future with similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, than I solved that way:

1. Create an Object called Error, like that (don't forget to implement Serializable...):

   ```
   private String fieldName;
   private String errorCode;
   private String defaultMessage;

   public Error() {
   }

   public Error(String fieldName, String errorCode, String defaultMessage) {
       this.fieldName = fieldName;
       this.errorCode = errorCode;
       this.defaultMessage = defaultMessage;
   }

   /* getters, setters */
   ```
2. Inside the `@RestController` method you ave to call `inputValidator.validate()` method (if you didn't create an Object Validator for your `UserInput` then we're really don't speaking the same language...)

   ```
   // validating the userInput
   userInputValidator.validate(userInput, bindingResult);

   if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
       List<Error> errors = new ArrayList<>(bindingResult.getErrorCount());
       for (FieldError fieldWithError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
           errors.add(new Error(fieldWithError.getField(), fieldWithError.getCode(), fieldWithError.getDefaultMessage()));
       }
       return errors;
   }

   // in case of success:
   return null;
   ```
3. Finally you'll have to translate the JSON object to your client side. You'll have two kind of objects:

   3.1. null (`undefined` depending on the language you're using)

   3.2. A JSON object like that:

   ```
   [
     {
       "fieldName": "name",
       "errorCode": "user.input.name.in.blank",
       "defaultMessage": "Insert a valid name!"
     },
     {
       "fieldName": "firstPhone",
       "errorCode": "user.input.first.phone.blank",
       "defaultMessage": "Insert a valid first phone!"
     }
   ]
   ```